# Highcharts Waterfall low value for yAxis point

Tags: highcharts

While testing Highcharts v6.0.7 I found that Waterfall chart yAxis point does not accept "low" value anymore (series.data.low). The same option in the Column chart works and the point does not start at the bottom but at the "low" value.

I tried it with an older version (4.2.3) and it works. The reason for using "low" value is that I want to have first point in Waterfall chart start at specified "low" value instead of the bottom of the chart.

I searched through the documentation and could not find any info about this, is this a bug or has this "low" option been removed. And if there is a workaround for this that would give me the same results.

Comment: Can't say I've heard of this `low` feature. Seems like a good question, but I think some example code would illuminate the problem. For example a simple column chart using a [old highcharts.js version](http://code.highcharts.com/4.2.3/highcharts.src.js).

Comment: Yes, I forgot examples. Here's the code in the latest version: https://codepen.io/pgusic/pen/xaEjEY

Comment: And the older version, where "low" is supported: https://codepen.io/pgusic/pen/MqjGeb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If something "worked" on specific version and wasn't documented at all (I checked the documentation of v4.2.3), then we can assume that was some type of undesirable behaviour. I see that 'waterfall' series inherits from column series, on which the low parameter still works as you described, but it also doesn't occurs in documentation.

If you would like to get similar effect, please try to use `series.threshold` parameter, but in my opinion both of ways breaks the logic of the chart a bit.

```
series: [{
    threshold: 100000,
    data: [{
        y: 120000,
    }, {
        y: 569000,
    }, {
        y: 231000
    }, {
        isIntermediateSum: true,
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
    }, {
        y: -342000
    }, {
        y: -233000
    }, {
        isSum: true,
}]
```

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/nxwy48uj/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.waterfall.threshold

Comment: Yes, there's nothing in the documentation so I guess you're right. Could be that they fixed a bug by removing the low parametar. I suppose threshold could be used. Thank you for the info.